# texture paint changed my image to be black

Tags: texture-painting

Hi i have an image and use it as texture. i applied to a cube and setup uv. Go to texture paint and paint using green brush . All the paint looks good in the viewer, but when i save all images and check the folder where the texture is saved , i only see my stroke with my original image become black. Is this a bug ? Does anyone has this experience ?

[image]

Comment: What happens when using the uv image editor as the painter?

Comment: @CraigDJones, I just found the fix. The image i use for the texture map is TIFF 16 bit which for whatever reason , it give me that black thing after i save the painted texture. So i export that 16 bit image to 8bit TIFF and it solve the problem. I don't know why , maybe this is a bug .

Comment: Perhaps include that as the answer and mark it accepted so later people will find this as a solved issue.

Comment: @CraigDJones Thanks , i 've just post the answer. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the fix for this. I realize that it happened when i use 16bit TIFF file as texture map. So everytime i do a texture painting and save the image, it will save only my stroke, while the original image become black. Then i fix this by using 8bit, so i convert that 16bit into 8bit TIFF then reload that texture map and it solves my problem. I currently use 2.79 , so maybe this is a bug.

Thanks.